# NSWindowController window property not initialized only on machines used by Apple Review Team

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to release an update for my app in Mac App Store. I already tested it on my Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra. But this version was rejected 4 times, because one of main windows is showing blank when Apple Review Team tests my app.

Here is what I have:

1. There is LPChannelsWindowController class with .h, .m files and generated automatically .xib file.
2. In AppDelegate there is strong property for this window
3. Also there is LPChannelsViewController class with .h, .m and .xib files. .xib file contains all controls and references to outlets in LPChannelsViewController.m

This is how I initialize this window:

```
self.channelsListWindowController = [[LPChannelsWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:NSStringFromClass(LPChannelsWindowController.class)];
[self.channelsListWindowController show];
```

In method **show**:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[self showWindow:nil];
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

windowDidLoad:

```
[super windowDidLoad];
self.channelsVC = [[LPChannelsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(LPChannelsViewController.class) bundle:nil];
self.window.contentView = self.channelsVC.view;
self.window.contentViewController = self.channelsVC;
self.window.title = @"Manage channels";
self.channelsVC.containingWindow = self.window;
```

It works fine on my Macbook, but Apple Review Teams everytime sends me this screenshot. And I'm running out of ideas what can be wrong here.

[image]

Even title of this window is not changing. That's why I think that window property of LPChannelsWindowController may be not initialized when windowDidLoad is called. Or is it possible that windowDidLoad wasn't called at all?

Comment: You are 100% your xib is called LPChannelsWindowController.xib?

Comment: Yes, I checked this. Otherwise it wouldn't work on all macs, even on my own. But it works on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: You are testing your app under what type of accounts?  Administrative, standard, guest...  Pick one and get one for free.

Comment: I tried both guest and standard accounts, on my Macbook wasn't any problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood after testing my app in Mavericks, the window wasn't filled with view from LPChannelsViewController, because it contained NSCollectionView with NSCollectionViewFlowLayout (available only in 10.11+).